# Why can't I add an instance of A to a collection declared as Set<? extends A>?

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
class Document { ... }

class DocumentCluster extends Document { ... }
```

And I'm trying to define a set of documents this way:

```
Set<? extends Document> docs = new HashSet<Document>();
```

However, when I'm trying to insert a document to my set:

```
docs.add(d);
```

I'm getting:

```
The method add(capture#10-of ? extends Document) in the type Set<capture#10-of ? extends Document> is not applicable for the arguments (Document)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `? extends` collections are immutable

Comment: @DanPantry That's not a very instructive way of putting it... Immutability is a runtime-enforced property, whereas generic types aren't.

Comment: I've rephrased in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it might only allow objects of type `B`.

A classic question, answered a million of times. Non-intuitive, but also not a design bug of Java.

Here is the classic example: let `A` be `Fruit`.

Can I put an `Apple` into a `Set<? extends Fruit>`?

**No**, because it could be a `Set<Banana>` which obviously *must not* contain apples.

`? extends Fruit` says *some **specific kind** of fruit*, and *not* "any kind of fruit". Then it would be a `Set<Fruit>` which indeed can take any kind of Fruit.

As a rule of thumb:

- when putting `? super Fruit` is convenient. It takes "at least" fruits
- when getting `? extends Fruit` is convenient. It may return only one kind of fruit, but they will all be fruit.

Consider this method:

```
public static double computeAverage(Collection<? extends Number> col) {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (Number n : col) {
      sum += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum / n.size();
}
```

This method *can* work with `List<Integer>`. Because it does *not* put `Double` into the list, but only takes `Number` objects out.

```
public static void put(Collection<? super Number> col, Number n) {
    col.put(n);
}
```

Here, we have the opposite case. We need a list that accepts *arbitrary* numbers (otherwise, we could not put the unspecific number in it). It may accept more, though:

```
put(new List<Object>(), (Double) 1.);
```

is valid, because I *may* put doubles into a list of Objects.

But the compiler *correctly* prevents `put( new List<Integer>(), (Double) 1.)`.

It can get much messier than that:

```
public static <I,O> void transfer(Collection<? extends I> input,
                                  Collection<? super O> output,
                                  Converter<? super I, ? extends O> converter) {
  for (I inobj : input) {
    O outobj = converter.convert(inobj);
    output.put(outobj);
  }
}
```

But the compiler may be unable to figure out `I` and `O` automatically for you every time.

Comment: So what are the benefits of using Set<? extends Fruit> to Set<Fruit> ?

Comment: That you can get `Fruit` out of a `Set<Apple>` without known what an `Apple` actually is.

Comment: This might need to be a new question but I might as well try. I need to pass Set<B> to a method accepting Set<A> where B extends A. Is casting the only solution?

Comment: No, the solution is to find out whether A) the *other* should have used `Set<? extends A>`, or B) it actually won't work. Casting is just pretending it will work somehow, despite your code saying that it is *incorrect*. I.e. casting may hide an API specification error.

Comment: Pretty much the *only* exception I know is due to a Java limitation involving `Class<?>` objects for *generic* types. Here, it may be necessary to cast e.g. `Class<Set<Integer>> klass = (Class<Set<Integer>>) Set.class;`. Note that this is a "cast to add Generic type arguments", it is not *changing* the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<? extends A>` can't be added to because you don't exactly what type you are adding to the collection, only that you are adding SOMETHING that extends A. You can guarentee that when you use `get()` you will get a class that extends A, but when you use `add()` because you don't know the definitive type, you can't add to the collection

If you want to take advantage of polymorphism, use `Set<A>`. This will do the exact same thing - any member that is type compatible, ie, extends, from `A` can be placed in the `Set<K>`.

EDIT:
@Anony-Mousse explained this much better with an example.